# How to override DI registration from other container in ASP.NET Core integration test

Tags: c#, integration-testing, autofac, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following registration in asp.net core startup.cs file:

```
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>();
    }
```

This is to configure the Autofac container. And I have another integration test project where I have a CustomWebApplicationFactory class and I'm trying to replace the implementation of IUserService interface.

```
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IUserService, TestUsersService>();
        });
    }
```

It seems not work when I debug the test project and the implementation of IUserService is still UserService.

I tried registering UserService directly in Startup.ConfigureServices method with ASP.NET Core built-in IServiceCollection and it worked when debugging:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();
```

So, how can I fix the problem when I use Autofac as the IoC container and the integration test project will work properly as I expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are likely running into an order of operations problem. In general, last in wins. That goes for Autofac and for the base Microsoft DI container.

Assuming [you've read through the docs on Autofac ASP.NET Core integration](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) you'll see that when `ConfigureContainer` is in place the order of operations is roughly:

- WebHost specific ConfigureServices
- Startup class ConfigureServices
- Startup class ConfigureContainer

When adding ConfigureTestServices in place, it looks like (though I haven't stepped through) it runs after the WebHost and Startup class ConfigureServices... but it's still running before ConfigureContainer.

This would be easy enough to test - create a service interface with three different implementations. Register a different implementation at each level. Resolve the interface in a controller. Which one did you get? That was the last one to run. Now remove that registration from the app and try again. What's the next one you get? That's the second to the last one. And so on.

Autofac takes a pre-built `IServicesCollection` and cycles through it, adding that to the native Autofac container. Once that's happened, it doesn't matter if you modify the collection. Autofac has no control over the order of the execution of the startup mechanism in ASP.NET Core; it just knows that ASP.NET Core says, "Here's the final service collection to go ahead and import!" If that's not happening at the right stage, you'll have to do one of two things:

- Move the registration you need to override out of `ConfigureContainer` and into one of the `ConfigureServices` methods, using the Microsoft registration language instead of native Autofac.
- Perform the override some other way like using an `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` setting of `Test` and providing a `ConfigureTestContainer` method. (Examples of environment specific registration methods are in [the docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html).)

Comment: Many thanks for helping. The problem was exactly the operation orders like you  said. The Startup.ConfigureContainer runs after ConfigureTestServices. I fix the problem by replacing ConfigureTestServices with another extension method called ConfigureTestContainer in my integration test project. This method runs after Startup.ConfigureContainer and that solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

When using ContainerBuilder like this:

```
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>();
    }
```

You must use ConfigureTestContainer rather than ConfigureTestServices as follows:

```
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder =>
            {
                containerBuilder.RegisterType<TestUsersService>().As<IUserService>();
            });
    }
```

This is executed after the call to ConfigureContainer and will correctly override `IUserService` with `TestUsersService`

Comment: Beware of this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14907

Answer (score 0):

For the ones coming from google I'd like to add to Michael's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911122/12124108) that `ConfigureTestContainer` does not work with the generic host [recommended over the web host by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1) as of .NET Core 3.0. There is however a [workaround proposed by Alistair Evans from the Autofac team](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/1207#issuecomment-701961371). Unfortunately, it relies on the deprecated `IStartupConfigureContainerFilter` that will probably be removed in .NET 5.0.

This means that currently in .NET 5.0 there is no way to mock dependencies injected by an external DI container in integration tests when using the generic host.

Luckily, David Fowler from the ASP.NET team [is looking into the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14907#issuecomment-592102145).