# How do I replace service implementations for Web API integration testing using TestHost.TestServer in .NET 5

Tags: .net, integration-testing, xunit, webapi, testserver

I am trying to move my integration tests from `WebApplicationFactory` to `TestServer` in .NET 5. In my existing implementation I can override `ConfigureWebHost` and call `IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices` to replace service implementations with mocks. This runs after the `Startup` code, allowing me to remove the production implementation and add the mock.

When trying to achieve the same thing using `TestServer`, `ConfigureServices` always runs *before* the `Startup` code, no matter in which order I do the configuration, meaning I always end up with both implementations in the services collection and it seems "last one wins", i.e. the prod version of the service always runs.

How can I configure the builder to use my test version?

I am using XUnit, so perhaps am not using it in the right way re `IClassFixture` etc.

Here is my code:

```cs
public sealed class IntegrationTests : IDisposable
{
    private TestServer Server { get; }
    private HttpClient Client { get; }

    public IntegrationTests()
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.development.json").Build())
            .UseSerilog()
            // Changing the order of the following two lines doesn't help
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureServices(UseDummyUserRepository);

        Server = new TestServer(builder);
        Client = Server.CreateClient();
    }

    private void UseDummyUserRepository(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Following line doesn't work as the service is not yet configured
        //services.Remove(services.First(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(IUserRepository)));
        services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, DummyUserRepository>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49377724/5816) about the existence of [TryAddTransient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.extensions.servicecollectiondescriptorextensions.tryaddtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), which does the job but feels like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

This post contains some more info which might be useful.

From my testing the order of execution in an integration test is as follows.

```
Startup.ConfigureServices
IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices
IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureTestServices
Startup.ConfigureContainer
```

So the issue comes when you attempt to override a service in IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices if that service is actually defined in Startup.ConfigureContainer

[I tried using IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureTestContainer but it did not appear to be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64316891/253131).

[How to override DI registration from other container in ASP.NET Core integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856614/how-to-override-di-registration-from-other-container-in-asp-net-core-integration)

Comment: .NET 5 reached End Of Life almost a year ago. There's no `Startup.cs` any more